# Traverse through a json in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, json

I want to traverse json and fetch the "Value" of elements "Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4". Is there a way to achieve it without using regex? I have read that using regex for json is not a good idea.

```
<script>
abc = {
"model": {
    "DataSection": {
        "Data1": {
            "Value": "1"
        },
        "Data2": {
            "Value": "2"
        },
        "Data3": {
            "Value": "3"
        },
        "Data4": {
            "Value": "4"
        }
    }
} 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are the levels of your json always the same?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy yes, they are always same

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is : `JSON.parse(string)`

But what you gave us is not JSON it is a javascript object

```js
abc = {
"model": {
    "DataSection": {
        "Data1": {
            "Value": "1"
        },
        "Data2": {
            "Value": "2"
        },
        "Data3": {
            "Value": "3"
        },
        "Data4": {
            "Value": "4"
        }
    }
} 
}

for (let data in abc.model.DataSection) {
  console.log(abc.model.DataSection[data].Value)
}
```

---

In case you truly have a JSON it would become

```js
abc = `{
"model": {
    "DataSection": {
        "Data1": {
            "Value": "1"
        },
        "Data2": {
            "Value": "2"
        },
        "Data3": {
            "Value": "3"
        },
        "Data4": {
            "Value": "4"
        }
    }
} 
}`
// abc is a string containing JSON

cde = JSON.parse(abc)
// cde is the object based on abc



for (let data in cde.model.DataSection) {
  console.log(cde.model.DataSection[data].Value)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, what I was asking is looping through that object using regex or a better method.

Comment: @john yep srry didn't read the good way first but edited and now it is good ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can do something without using regex then do. Here I create an array and put all the values in it.

```js
abc = {
  "model": {
    "DataSection": {
      "Data1": {
        "Value": "1"
      },
      "Data2": {
        "Value": "2"
      },
      "Data3": {
        "Value": "3"
      },
      "Data4": {
        "Value": "4"
      }
    }
  }
}

var array = []

$.each(abc.model.DataSection, function(index, value) {
  array.push(value.Value)
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```